# echo 100 - 99.9; gives 0.099999999999994 in php

Tags: php, operators

I was trying something and I ran into this problem:

```
<?php    
echo 100 - 99.9;
// gives: 0.099999999999994
```

can anyone tell me why this happened and how can I fix this?

Comment: `round(100 - 99.9, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is it's floating point number read why this happens here https://floating-point-gui.de/ more info is also avalible here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php TLDR: Floating point numbers have small difrenses at the end.